# Find the sum of the series using Taylor expansion

Tags: taylor-expansion

Find the following sum

> $$
> \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{3n}}{(3n)!},    
> x \in \Bbb R
> $$

Comment: What have you tried ? This is a classic sum, have you ever heard of the multisection formula ?

Comment: Call this $f(x)$ and call $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ the similar series with $3n+1$ and $3n+2$. Then $f(x)+g(x)+h(x)=e^x$. Now compute $\exp(ax)$ with some carefully chosen complex $a$ such that $|a|=1$. The goal is to find two other independant linear combinations of $f$, $g$, $h$ with known values, and to solve the linear system to find $f,g,h$.

Comment: Never. We haven't learned about that yet, but i want to know it. Is this a usual Calculus or what subject is it? I have tried enough, to understand that i don`t know how to solve it.

Comment: @B1ZON It helps, on this site, to include some extra context. Even if you don't have any initial ideas on how to attack this problem, perhaps you could list some techniques you've covered recently in class? There are a great number of ways to solve a problem like this, so it helps to get some direction as to which ones will help you the most. (Try editing the question, otherwise the "close" votes will accumulate.)

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_multisection):

> $$\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{z^{3m}}{(3m)!}=\frac{1}{3}\left(e^z + 2e^{-z/2}\cos\frac{\sqrt{3}z}{2}\right)$$ So, probably your teacher took the question from Wikipedia.

Comment: @B1ZON Another way to go about this is to notice that, if $f(x)$ is the function of $x$ defined by this series (which converges everywhere), then $f'''(x) = f(x)$. This means it's the solution to a homogeneous, linear, constant coefficient ODE with characteristic polynomial $r^3 = 1$. If you compute $f(0), f'(0), f''(0)$, you can turn this into a tractable initial value problem.

Comment: @TheoBendit thanks a lot. Honestly, it is the first time i facing with such thing. Pls tell me where can i get more of this tasks? Or some books. Is it still calculus or other branch of math? It is task from local math competition and i`d like to solve more of this.

Comment: A simple way to cancel all but every third term is to use the third roots of unity:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{3n}}{(3n)!}
&=\frac13\left(e^x+e^{\left(-\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)x}+e^{\left(-\frac12-i\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)x}\right)\\
&=\frac13e^x+\frac23e^{-x/2}\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt3}2x\right)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: That uses the iidentity $$ \frac1c\sum_{d=0}^{c-1}e^{2\pi ijd/c}=[\,c\mid j\,] $$ as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2444346).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is an expansion on my comment above.)

Let
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{3n}}{(3n)!}.$$

Using the ratio test, we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{x^{3(n+1)}}{(3(n+1))!} \div \frac{x^{3n}}{(3n)!} \right| = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{|x|^3}{(3n+3)(3n+2)(3n+1)} = 0 < 1,$$
regardless of the value of $x$. Thus, the series converges everywhere. As usual, with power series, the resulting series is infinitely differentiable, and derivatives can be computed termwise. In particular,
\begin{align*}
f'(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty 3n\frac{x^{3n - 1}}{(3n)!} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 3n\frac{x^{3n - 1}}{(3n)!} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{3n - 1}}{(3n - 1)!} =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{3n + 2}}{(3n + 2)!} \\
f''(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{3n + 1}}{(3n + 1)!} \\
f'''(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{3n}}{(3n)!} = f(x).
\end{align*}
In particular, $f'''(x) = f(x)$. We also have,
\begin{align*}
f(0) &= 1 + \frac{0}{3!} + \frac{0}{6!} + \ldots = 1 \\
f'(0) &= \frac{0}{2!} + \frac{0}{5!} + \frac{0}{8!} + \ldots = 0 \\
f''(0) &= \frac{0}{1!} + \frac{0}{4!} + \frac{0}{7!} + \ldots = 0.
\end{align*}
So, our function is the (necessarily unique) solution to the IVP:
$$y''' - y = 0, \, y(0) = 1, y'(0) = 0, y''(0) = 0$$
The usual way to solve such problems is to use the characteristic polynomial. In particular, the characteristic polynomial is $r^3 - 1$. We solve this over $\mathbb{C}$ by completing the square:
\begin{align*}
0 &= r^3 - 1 \\
&= (r - 1)(r^2 + r + 1) = (r - 1)\left(r^2 + r + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{4}\right) \\
&= (r - 1)\left(\left(r + \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i\right)^2\right) \\
&= (r - 1)\left(r + \frac{1}{2} - i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\left(r + \frac{1}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right),
\end{align*}
yielding $r = 1$ or $r = \frac{-1 \pm i\sqrt{3}}{2}$ (there are many ways to do this, including quadratic formula or $n$th roots of unity formulae, but I just like completing the square).

So we have a real root $r = 1$, which says that one fundamental solution will be $e^x$. We also have a pair of complex conjugates $r = -\frac{1}{2} \pm i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, which suggests the other fundamental solutions are $e^{-x/2}\cos(x\sqrt{3}/2)$ and $e^{-x/2}\sin(x\sqrt{3}/2)$. Therefore, the general solution of the differential equation (ignoring initial values) is
$$f(x) = Ae^x + Be^{-\frac{x}{2}}\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} x\right) + Ce^{-\frac{x}{2}}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} x\right).$$
Differentiating, using product rule when necessary,
\begin{align*}
f'(x) &= Ae^x + \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}C - \frac{1}{2}B\right)e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} x\right) + \left(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}B - \frac{1}{2}C\right)e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} x\right) \\
f''(x) &= Ae^x + \left(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}C - \frac{1}{2}B\right)e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} x\right) + \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}B - \frac{1}{2}C\right)e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} x\right)
\end{align*}
Using the values of $f(0)$, $f'(0)$, and $f''(0)$, we can compute these constants. We have
\begin{align*}
1 &= f(0) = A + B \\
0 &= f'(0) = A - \frac{1}{2} B + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} C \\
0 &= f''(0) = A - \frac{1}{2} B - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} C.
\end{align*}

Adding all three equations yields $3A = 1$, hence $A = \frac{1}{3}$. Adding the second two equations yields $0 = 2A - B = \frac{2}{3} - B$, hence $B = \frac{2}{3}$. Subtracting the second two equations yields $C = 0$. So, our one and only solution is,
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{3}e^x + \frac{2}{3}e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} x\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: start with Taylor's expansion for the exponential
$$
e^{\omega x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\omega^k x^k}{k!}
$$
and try to find $\omega\in\Bbb C$ such that
$$
\langle\text{a polynomial of }\omega^k\rangle=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if }3\nmid k,\\
\ne 0 & \text{if }3\mid k.
\end{cases}
$$
Play around with the third root of unity and the formula
$$
\alpha^3-1=(\alpha-1)(\alpha^2+\alpha+1).
$$

Comment: It's the idea, but it's going to be slightly more complicated: if $\omega^k=0$ for some integer $k$, then $\omega=0$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Oops, thanks, it was too optimistic :)